# Problems creating a server with node, getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, localhost

I hit a snag in a javascript course and was hoping to get some help here. In this lesson, I'm using node with express to create a server and connect it with MongoDB. Everything was working fine and then suddenly I was unable to connect with the local host. I'm a total newbie with this stuff, so I have no clue what's happening. Whenever I try to start the server in my terminal, I get a big error message that includes these errors:

```
    db = client.db();
                  ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null

 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting
```

This chunk of code seems to be where the problem is stemming from but again, I have no clue:

```
mongodb.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(
  err,
  client
) {
  db = client.db();
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

I understand there are already threads here about this issue but they don't seem to address my particular issue and I can't make sense out of the answers. I'd appreciate any help and please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please output `err` it will give you an error message.

Comment: Are you able to log "client" ? I'd like to know if you're even getting a callback or if you're getting an error. You don't seem to be handling the error.

Comment: @RolandStarke Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I looked up 'output err' but I can't figure out what that is. I'm brand new to this haha!

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas I don't know how to log "client" lol, I'm a baby with this stuff!

Comment: No problem, so before `db = client.db();` add the line `console.log(err);`.

Comment: @RolandStarke I decided to just start the lesson over from scratch but thanks so much for your reply, I'll try that if I run into the same error!